# Understanding the "left_index" and "right_index" arguments in pandas merge

Tags: python, pandas, join, merge

I am really struggling to understand the "left_index" and "right_index" arguments in pandas.merge. I read the documentation, searched around, experimented with various setting and tried to understand but I am still confused. Consider this example:

```
left = pd.DataFrame({'key1': ['K0', 'K0', 'K1', 'K2'], 
                 'key2': ['K0', 'K1', 'K0', 'K1'],
                 'A': ['A0', 'A1', 'A2', 'A3'],
                 'B': ['B0', 'B1', 'B2', 'B3']})

right = pd.DataFrame({'key1': ['K0', 'K1', 'K1', 'K2'],
                      'key2': ['K0', 'K0', 'K0', 'K0'],
                      'C': ['C0', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3'],
                      'D': ['D0', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3'],
                      'E': [1,2,3,4]})
```

Now, when I run the following command:

```
pd.merge(left, right, left_on=['key2', 'key1'], right_on=['key1', 'key2'], how='outer', indicator=True, left_index=True)
```

I get:

```
  key1_x key2_x    A    B key1_y key2_y    C    D    E      _merge
0     K0     K0   A0   B0     K0     K0   C0   D0  1.0        both
1     K0     K1   A1   B1     K1     K0   C1   D1  2.0        both
2     K0     K1   A1   B1     K1     K0   C2   D2  3.0        both
3     K1     K0   A2   B2    NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   left_only
3     K2     K1   A3   B3    NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN   left_only
3    NaN    NaN  NaN  NaN     K2     K0   C3   D3  4.0  right_only
```

However, running the same with `right_index=True` gives an error. Same if I introduce both. More interestingly, running the following merge gives a very unexpected result

```
pd.merge(left, right,  on=['key1', 'key2'],how='outer', validate = 'one_to_many', indicator=True, left_index = True, right_index = True)
```

Result is:

```
  key1 key2   A   B   C   D  E _merge
0   K0   K0  A0  B0  C0  D0  1   both
1   K0   K1  A1  B1  C1  D1  2   both
2   K1   K0  A2  B2  C2  D2  3   both
3   K2   K1  A3  B3  C3  D3  4   both
```

As you can see, all information for right frame for `key1` and `key2` is completely lost.

Please help me understand the purpose and function of these arguments. Thank you.

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html read the link and I think the definition already there

Comment: As mentioned in the first line of the post, I did indeed read it. Not clear what they mean here "Use the index from the left DataFrame as the join key(s)". Because when I tried to do that and match is with something on the right side, it throws an error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If I understand the behavior of `merge` correctly, you should pick only one option for `left` and `right` respectively (i.e. You **should not** pick `left_on=['x']` and `left_index=True` at the same time). Otherwise, strange thing can happen in arbitrary way since it confuses `merge` as to which `key` should be actually used as you have shown in current implementation of `merge` (I have not checked the pandas source in detail, but the behavior can change for different implementations in each version). Here is a small experiment.

```
>>> left
  key1 key2   A   B
0   K0   K0  A0  B0
1   K0   K1  A1  B1
2   K1   K0  A2  B2
3   K2   K1  A3  B3

>>> right
  key1 key2   C   D  E
0   K0   K0  C0  D0  1
1   K1   K0  C1  D1  2
2   K1   K0  C2  D2  3
3   K2   K0  C3  D3  4
```

(1) `merge` using `['key1', 'key2']`

```
>>> pd.merge(left, right, on=['key1', 'key2'], how='outer')

  key1 key2    A    B    C    D    E
0   K0   K0   A0   B0   C0   D0  1.0
1   K0   K1   A1   B1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   K1   K0   A2   B2   C1   D1  2.0
3   K1   K0   A2   B2   C2   D2  3.0
4   K2   K1   A3   B3  NaN  NaN  NaN
5   K2   K0  NaN  NaN   C3   D3  4.0
```

(2) Set `['key1', 'key2']` as `left` index and `merge` it using the index and keys

```
>>> left = left.set_index(['key1', 'key2'])
>>> pd.merge(left, right, left_index=True, right_on=['key1', 'key2'], how='outer').reset_index(drop=True)

     A    B key1 key2    C    D    E
0   A0   B0   K0   K0   C0   D0  1.0
1   A1   B1   K0   K1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   A2   B2   K1   K0   C1   D1  2.0
3   A2   B2   K1   K0   C2   D2  3.0
4   A3   B3   K2   K1  NaN  NaN  NaN
5  NaN  NaN   K2   K0   C3   D3  4.0
```

(3) Further set `['key1', 'key2']` as `right` index and `merge` it using the index

```
>>> right = right.set_index(['key1', 'key2'])
>>> pd.merge(left, right, left_index=True, right_index=True, how='outer').reset_index()

  key1 key2    A    B    C    D    E
0   K0   K0   A0   B0   C0   D0  1.0
1   K0   K1   A1   B1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2   K1   K0   A2   B2   C1   D1  2.0
3   K1   K0   A2   B2   C2   D2  3.0
4   K2   K0  NaN  NaN   C3   D3  4.0
5   K2   K1   A3   B3  NaN  NaN  NaN
```

Please note that (1)(2)(3) above are showing the same results, and even if `['key1', 'key2']` are set as index, you can still use `left_on = ['key1', 'key2']` instead of `left_index=True`.

Now, if you really want to merge using both `['key1', 'key2']` with `index`, one way to achieve this is:

```
>>> pd.merge(left.reset_index(), right.reset_index(), on=['index', 'key1', 'key2'], how='outer')

   index key1 key2    A    B    C    D    E
0      0   K0   K0   A0   B0   C0   D0  1.0
1      1   K0   K1   A1   B1  NaN  NaN  NaN
2      2   K1   K0   A2   B2   C2   D2  3.0
3      3   K2   K1   A3   B3  NaN  NaN  NaN
4      1   K1   K0  NaN  NaN   C1   D1  2.0
5      3   K2   K0  NaN  NaN   C3   D3  4.0
```

If you read down to here, I'm pretty sure now you know how to achieve above using multiple different ways.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 12):

## Merging happens in a couple of ways:

**Column-Column Merge:** Use left_on, right_on and how.

Example:

```
# Gives same answer
pd.merge(left, right, left_on=['key2', 'key1'], right_on=['key1', 'key2'], how = 'outer')
pd.merge(left, right, on=['key1', 'key2'], how='outer', indicator=True)
```

**Index-Index Merge:** Set left_index and right_index to True or use on and use how.

Example:

```
pd.merge(left, right, how = 'inner', right_index = True, left_index = True)
# If you make matching unique multi-indexes for both data frames you can do
# pd.merge(left, right, how = 'inner', on = ['indexname1', 'indexname2'])
# In your data frames, you're keys duplicate values so you can't do this
# In general, a column with duplicate values does not make a good key
```

**Column-Index Merge:** Use left_on + right_index or left_index + right_on and how.

Note: Both the values in index and left_on must match. If you're index is a integer and you're left_on is a string, you get error. Also, number of indexing levels must match.

Example:

```
# If how not specified, inner join is used
pd.merge(left, right, right_on=['E'], left_index = True, how = 'outer')  

# Gives error because left_on is string and right_index is integer
pd.merge(left, right, left_on=['key1'], right_index = True, how = 'outer')

# This gave you error because left_on has indexing level of 2 but right_index only has indexing level of 1.
pd.merge(left, right, left_on=['key2', 'key1'], right_on=['key1', 'key2'], how='outer', indicator=True, right_index=True)
```

You kind of mix up the different types of merges which gave weird results.
If you can't see how the merging is going to happen conceptually, chances are a computer isn't going to do any better.